# How to create an endpoint with optional parameters? (Node, Express, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, api-design, optional-parameters

I have created a MongoDB with two main entities CATS and BREEDS (one-to-many) but I have never worked with optional parameters.

I want to handle the following requests.

- A 'GET' request to fetch all the cats (with an optional param that will
  determine if the description should be returned as well, and another optional
  param to filter by breed)
- A 'GET request to fetch a specific cat (with an optional param
  that will determine if the payload will be returned as well) either by
  name or by id

I include my DB schemas in case they are needed.

```
const CatSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    breed: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Breed"
    }
});

const BreedSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a question mark to make your param optional.
`/cats/:description?`

You can also use multiple optional parameters.
`/cats/:description?/:breed?`

Edit,
be sure to check the params with:

```
if(description) {
    //show cats with description
}
```

Something like that.